# Mouse / Touchpad Buttons above touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, ubuntu-mate

I have a rather new Lenovo P14s running Ubuntu-MATE 21.10.

[image]

**How can I activate the left and right „mouse“ button on the touchpad (marked red). Currently they are completely inactive. (under Linux, not (dual boot) under Windows so not a hardware issue)**

The *green* corners on the touchpad itself do work as mouse buttons, even hold and drag (i.e dragging around Windows on screen).

(under MATE there is no such thing as `gnome-tweak`, only a `mate-tweak` with nothing specific into this direction)

Comment: There's no point in troubleshooting a release that will become EoL in a few days.

Comment: I don't think, this problem is limited to a particular release.

Comment: ...but you don't know unless you at least try a supported release like the current 22.04 in a live session.

Comment: open a terminal and type `xev`. press the buttons and see if they respond. If so you can attach an action to the buttons. If not either the kernel or your bios needs updating  (I agreee with @ChanganAuto on this: a newer Ubuntu (ie. newer kernel) might fix this. also because of this "a rather new Lenovo")

Comment: Don't make any changes to kernel modules (ie. *drivers* the common term) as they'll only take effect until you *release-upgrade* to 22.04 as it uses a different kernel; ie. I'd suggest *release-upgrading* first... https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/

Comment: `xev` shows... nothing for the two buttons. I will check at home if my elder lenovos (with even elder Ubuntus, and NO problems) show something with `xev`...  good idea!

Comment: `xinput --test-xi2` (no id given==across all xinput devices) gives me lots of things, also `RawButtonPress/Release` in the working green area, but NOTHING on the 'red' buttons, so yes, I think, you are right, suspecting the kernel.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: How did you fix this issue? I am facing the same issue in my 480s & I am running ubuntu 22 LTS. 

`# uname -r
5.15.0-92-generic`

`# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy`

`# dmidecode -s bios-version
N22ET46W (1.23 )`

Answer (score 0):

In my case these were disabled.
I was able to enable them.
Open your setting - mouse and touch-pad it should look something like this.

FYI: it is on ubuntu 20.04
[image]

Comment: Thank you, sadly things loook slightly different under the MATE-Flavour, und I don't get the buttons to work (tapping on the main touch surface does work and did before)